# Audio decoding stopped working ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, decoding

I wrote little program for extracting raw audio date a little while ago. I was busy and in meanwhile I changed OS from Kubuntu 15.04 to 16.04. Libraries are dynamically linked in cmakelists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(
    ffmpeg 
#[[ Linking ffmpeg libraries - START ------------------]]
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern_libs/libffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.so"
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern_libs/libffmpeg/lib/libavdevice.so"
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern_libs/libffmpeg/lib/libavutil.so"
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern_libs/libffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.so"
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern_libs/libffmpeg/lib/libavformat.so"
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern_libs/libffmpeg/lib/libswresample.so"
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern_libs/libffmpeg/lib/libswscale.so" 
#[[ Linking ffmpeg libraries - END --------------------]]
)
```

I started working again on my code but code doesn't work anymore.

```
if(av_read_frame(m_ctx, &avpkt) >= 0){
        got_frame = 0;
        avcodec_decode_audio4(c, decoded_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);

        detectSampleFormat((AVSampleFormat)decoded_frame->format);
        m_data->allocateMemory(m_duration, decoded_frame->channels);
        m_resampler->initResampler(m_fmt, decoded_frame->channel_layout, decoded_frame->sample_rate, decoded_frame->nb_samples);
        m_resampler->resampleAudioFrame(decoded_frame, m_data);     
    }

    while(av_read_frame(m_ctx, &avpkt) >= 0){
        got_frame = 0;
        avcodec_decode_audio4(c, decoded_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);
        m_resampler->resampleAudioFrame(decoded_frame, m_data);     

    }
```

Decoded frame should contain information as channel_layout, number of channels and so on... But during execution of program those are 0 or nulls.

Can anyone help me with this? I am unclear why this was working some while ago (I last worked on this code in March) and same code doesn't work anymore.

EDIT: 
I found problem. First frame which is read from file is damaged or something, so I just waited for first correct frame to initialize my components.

This question can be closed.